# Como posso colocar pagina fixa na parte de cima de todas a paginas que abrir no electron?

Tags: javascript, html, webforms, navegador-de-internet, electron

Estou com uma duvida de como fixar coisas a cima no electron usando js ou alguma extensão do electron. Estilo qualquer navegador web. E mesmo que mude para uma url da internet, continuar fixa em cima.

Alguém sabe como pode ser feito isso ?

Gostaria de fazer um arquivo "menu.html" e colocar em todas as paginas, e caso seja direcionada a uma web, exemplo "google.com" ela continuasse fixa na parte de cima, igual o codigo a baixo, só que podendo personalizar em html. Alguem?

```
function createWindow () {

  // Other code removed for brevity

  var menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
      {
          label: 'Menu',
          submenu: [
              {label:'Adjust Notification Value'},
              {label:'CoinMarketCap'},
              {label:'Exit'}
          ]
      }
  ])
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu); 

}
```

Comment: Este código cria um menu nativo do sistema. Com HTML o menu desaparece a não ser que use uma iFrame.

Comment: como assim ? não entendi ao certo